# package com.google.common.collect does not exist on netbeans

Tags: package, netbeans-8

I imported a project on netbeans and it says the package does not exist.
the error is in these two lines.

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the google collections `.jar` files from the internet
2. In your project go to libraries -> Add jar/folder
3. Locate the `.jar` files in your computer and add them

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add "guava 19.0.jar" under dependencies